# Error performing checksum

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, redhat

While installing package using yum it throws

`[Errno -3] Error performing checksum`

I found the specific package has been upgraded to checksum download option. How to fix this issue?

I tried to create `createrepo -dv .` and changing base url in `/etc/yum.conf`, but didn't yield any result. Basically I am facing while installing rails in linux:

`Linux xxxx 2.6.18-371.0.0.0.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Oct 1 05:48:31 PDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
bash-3.2$ sudo yum install gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel
Password:
base                                                                                              | 1.9 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
el5_latest                                                                                        | 1.4 kB     00:00
epel                                                                                              | 3.7 kB     00:00
hudson                                                                                            | 2.9 kB     00:00
hudson/primary_db                                                                                 | 4.8 kB     00:00
http://hudson-ci.org/redhat/repodata/6033de5d5abbc355e98d833bbc0b821cdbad47f72b7fafe0fb82c297197f66dc-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
hudson/primary_db                                                                                 | 4.8 kB     00:00
http://hudson-ci.org/redhat/repodata/6033de5d5abbc355e98d833bbc0b821cdbad47f72b7fafe0fb82c297197f66dc-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/6033de5d5abbc355e98d833bbc0b821cdbad47f72b7fafe0fb82c297197f66dc-primary.sqlite.bz2 from hudson: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Answer (score 1):

I able to resolve in OEL6 version.